# How to retrieve the number of copies of a book PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

Hi I'm trying to write a procedure that retrieves the number of copies of a specific book from a table I have created.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE book_count(c_isbn IN book_copies.isbn%TYPE)
IS
total number;

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM book_copies
WHERE isbn = c_isbn;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Book count: ' || total);
END book_count;
```

The error I'm having is that an INTO clause is expected in the SELECT statement, but I can't seem to get it done. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE book_count(c_isbn IN book_copies.isbn%TYPE)
IS
total number;

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO TOTAL
FROM book_copies
WHERE isbn = c_isbn;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Book count: ' || total);
END book_count;
```

Comment: @Aleksej Bro, INTO TOTAL is added by me, it is not present in the actual question.

Comment: Thanks the Into total is what I was missing but it doesn't seem to be outputting the actual results in the script Output?

Comment: What is the actual result and what is the value that you are getting? Can you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: The DBMS Output has nothing in it & and Script Output is "Procedure Book_Count complied"

Comment: Is your server output on? Syntax is : set serveroutput on [size N|unlimited] example set serveroutput on size 30000;

Answer (score 0):

you can´t just use plain SQL in a begin end block. you need to insert as many variables in the `into clause`, immediatly after the select, that it matches the amount of columns you select.

You either need to do

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
into total
FROM book_copies
WHERE isbn = c_isbn;
```

or

```
for i in ( 
    SELECT COUNT (*) count
    FROM book_copies
    WHERE isbn = c_isbn;
)
loop
   total := i.count;
end loop;
```

keep in mind that the upper one can throw two exceptions, no_data_found and to_many_rows, while the loop has to notice this "mistake" manually.

Comment: Thanks the Into total is what I was missing but it doesn't seem to be outputting the actual results in the script Output?